# Gathering multiple Excel spreadsheets into one big DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, glob

I have a folder with multiple excel files (all have the same headers and I'm trying to concatenate the information together in a DataFrame, I'm having trouble creating a loop which iterates through every file and merges them together. The problem is that it goes on for the 30+files in the folder and just prints the same information over and over again.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
path = '/users/.../.../.../folder'
files = os.listdir(path)
print (files)

datafiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
for datafile in datafiles:
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel(datafiles)

for datafile in datafiles:
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel(datafile))

big_frame = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True) 
print(big_frame)

for df in dfs:
    big_frame.append(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    print(dfs)
```

What mistake am I making? The output should theoretically be one big dataframe with all the information from the 30+ files all appended together.

Comment: `big_frame = pd.concat(dfs)` would be enough.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked.